# Help with understanding similar matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Going over past notes I do not understand the concept of similar matrices and fail to see how my lecturer has got these Eigenvectors associated to the values, I think I'm missing something can someone help in layman terms.
[image]

Comment: Those are **eigenvectors**, no "eugene", and if you haven't yet understood this then you may need to go over your notes and for quite a while to fully understand this subject. I doubt this can be done in this site. Now, if you have a **particular** question then you can ask it.

Comment: @Joanpemo I was using my phone for the initial post and it simply corrected a slight spelling mistake on the original word, thanks for all the help you have given, i have read through my notes hence why i have turn't to stack exchange for someone to explain with a different perspective. The **particular** question i asked was how has he formed these vectors, i understand using reduced row echelon form to  create a system, however i thought you had to sub each eigen value into the characteristic polynomial to get the respected eigenvectors, also why is each value associated with that vector

Comment: In a situation like this it would be best to look at material that is not from your course, in the best case that would be a book on linear algebra (specifically diagonalization) or a script from a lecture on the subject. I may type out some pointers later when I have time, but getting a second source and just read is what you should do now.

Comment: @user In this particular example you wrote the eigenvalues are trivially the entries on the main diagonal. In general, you have to find the zeros of the polynomial $\;\det(xI-A)\;$ (the characteristic polynomial of the matrix $\;A\;$), and when you have them then you input each one of them in $\;xI-A\;$ and get a homogeneous linear system the solution space of which is precisely the space of eigenvectors of $\;A\;$ corresponding to the particular eigenvalue you input.

Comment: @Joanpemo why is the eigen vector for -1 (1 0 0) when x1 column is empty?

Comment: @user310686 I don't understand what "x1 column is empty" means. That the vector $\;u:=(1,0,0)^t\;$ is in eigenvector of $\;A\;$ with respect to the eigenvalue $\;-1\;$ is trivial: because $\;Au=-u=(-1)u\;$ . As simple as that.

Comment: @Joanpemo when you times the matrix A by u the iinitial column system is : u2     =0                                                                                        
           u3=0
 I do not see how this corresponds to (1 0 0 )

Comment: @user310686 If you mean "when you *multiply* the matrix by the vector $\;u\;$ , then you get what I wrote in my past comment. I honestly have no idea what you mean by "initial column system" ...

Comment: @user310686 Keep in mind that the solution to the equation $(A+I)v = 0$ is not unique. You could take any real (nonzero) multiple of it, or more specifically any vector $(a, 0, 0)$ for $a\in\mathbb R, a\neq 0$. So what happened is that one specific (arbitrary) solution was selected, namely the vector $(1,0,0)$.

Comment: @blue ah i see thankyou  this clears things up, just another quick question does the order of eigenvectors in a matrix matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you some pointers, however I strongly suggest you read about the subject in a source that is independent from your lecture, because getting a second perspective can be better than brooding over course material.

If you have a triangular matrix, the eigenvalues can be read from the diagonal; this follows from considering the characteristic polynomials, I will not go into detail here. In general consider the equation $Av = \lambda v$ where $A$ is a matrix, $v\neq 0$ is a vector and $\lambda\neq 0$. If such an equation holds, then $v$ is called an eigenvector and $\lambda$ is called an eigenvalue of $A$ (this is the definition of these terms). Note that $v\neq 0$ is key for this to make sense, but you can have $\lambda =0$. So If you know an eigenvalue $\lambda$, you can compute an associated eigenvector by solving $Av = \lambda v$ which is equivalent to $(A-\lambda I)v = 0$. This is what your instructor does to obtain the eigenvectors.

The aim now is to diagonalize the matrix and to do this one uses the eigenvectors. I will explain why $P^{-1}AP$ is diagonal, since you might not have seen why. Put the eigenvectors $v_1, \dots, v_n$ (that correspond to the eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n$) as column vectors in a matrix denoted by $P$ (perhaps $n=3$ in your case). Also let $e_1, \dots, e_n$ be the standard basis. Since the k-th column of $P$ is $v_k$, we have $Pe_k = v_k$ and $P^{-1}v_k = e_k$ for any k. Remember $Av_k = \lambda_k v_k$ since these are eigenvalue-eigenvector pairs. So 
$$P^{-1}AP e_k = P^{-1}A v_k = P^{-1}\lambda_k v_k = \lambda_k e_k.$$
This shows that the k-th column of $P^{-1}AP$ is $\lambda_k e_k$, so it is diagonal with $\lambda_k$ in the k-th entry.

From the calculation you can see that reordering the $v_k$ will change the order in which the $\lambda_k$ appear on the diagonal, but not much else. Obviously, the values $\lambda_k$ on the diagonal are the eigenvalues of the original matrix. There's still more to be said here like what happens when you have multiple linear independent eigenvectors for the same eigenvalue and why $P^{-1}$ is invertible, but in your example these are no concern.